# Redirect everything to index.php

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to do clean URLs by exploding `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then switching between the results.

However, once a user goes outside `index.php`, I'm assuming I need to redirect them back to `index.php` in order to process the URL they want to reach.  How can I accomplish this?

So for instance, if the user goes to `www.domain.com/home/johndoe/...` I'd like `index.php` (`domain.com/index.php`) to be hit so that it can process the `/home/johndoe/` via `request_uri`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @pixel: This is the most common way of doing it. If a file or directory is not found by apache, it will call call index.php. Now you can access the requested uri in your index.php with `$_GET['param']`. Note: on certain setups `RewriteBase /` can cause problems. If so, just comment it out with a pound sign.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to map URLs based on regular expressions, including sending everything to `index.php`,

Comment: Never really liked the apache docs... too wordy when you are looking for a specific thing

Answer (score 2):

You will need images, and other files what will show up in the index.php.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Turns on the Rewite Engine

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
```

If the filename is not equal JPG, JPEG... which need for index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

"Redirect" to index.php.

**In use:**

With PHP `$_GET` the `q` will give you the `/articles/1987/12/20/Répa's birthday/`

If you split the variable in every slash with

```
list($type, $date_year, $date_month, $date_day, $title) = split('[/-]', $_GET['q']);
```

You will got exactly what you want.

Comment: That rewrite condition is a bit excessive, and will break things if you end up saving files without file extensions (which could definitely happen).