# Smart URI handling for a CMS engine?

Tags: php, uri, url-rewriting

I am writing a CMS engine that improves upon the blog engine on my website. So far, the existing blog only has one smart URI handler - one that converts `/123` into `/blog.php?p=123` and that's currently done by a few `mod_rewrite` statments. I am afraid that this method is unwieldy and kludgy for when I have more "smart URIs" in my CMS.

At the moment, I've thought about a way that could do this in PHP, but it also seems semantically "evil". I'd get the `ErrorDocument 404` to use a PHP script that parses URIs and includes proper scripts dynamically (changing the statuscode to `200` on the way).

Should I do that? Are there better ways? I'm aiming for a neat smart URI parsing just like on Launchpad.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method is to redirect *everything* to index.php via mod_rewrite, and do all url parsing in php code. See for example [Redirect everything to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669258/redirect-everything-to-index-php/2669298#2669298)