# htaccess to forward to get URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My Google searching seems to be yielding examples for the opposite direction of where I want to go! I'm trying to get requests for `site1.org/aff/affusername` to redirect to `site2.com/aff/index.php?aff=affusername`, WHILE redirecting `site1.org` to `site2.com`. What's the best way to do this? I was trying to accomplish the specific redirection to GET with this, but it doesn't redirect anywhere at all:

```
RewriteRule ^/aff/(.+) http://www.site2.com/index.php\?aff=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to redirect only the aff staff, try to use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.org
RewriteRule ^aff/(.+)$ http://www.site2.com/aff/index.php?aff=$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(admin|user)/ # Add here any exclude folders you wish
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^aff/(.+)$ aff/index.php?aff=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Check this article if you wish to redirect all staff to your index.php: [Redirect everything to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669258/redirect-everything-to-index-php)

Basically the idea is to check if requested file doesn't exists redirect it to index.php

I edited the code above according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks - I tried the aff redirect but it isn't forwarding. Does it make a difference that the directory no longer exists on the original site?

Comment: It works!!! Sweet!!! Thank you. So, if I wanted to redirect site1.org to site2.com AND site1.org/aff/whatever to site2.com/aff/index.php?aff=whatever, would I put these rules in the same htaccess file? Or do I need to add in an exception instead?

Comment: Oh, wait, it's not redirecting correctly to the aff directory on site2.com. I modified as follows: RewriteRule ^/aff/(.+)$ http: //www.site2.com/aff/index.php?aff=$1 [R=permanent,L] but it's still redirecting straight to site2.com/index.php?aff=whatever

Comment: Obviously, with 301 redirects, I have to clear the browser to try again, oops. It works great, this is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Then only thing missing was the aff directory in site 2, but it's working great since I added it. I do have another related question at this point. On the htaccess for this site2, I need to forward /variousdirectories to /aff/index.php?aff=variousdirectories but keep hitting endless redirect loops. Once I get THAT down, I'll work on excluding certain directories which do NOT need to be forwarded, and make pretty the URL in the aff directory (but not until the script gets that parameter), but I might actually be able to help myself on the last 2 points, just not this first one apparently.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote, but when I do I am going to vote bigtime on this! Thank you - this is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aff/(.*) http://www.site2.com/index.php\?aff=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works great!!! Except, it's not redirecting to the aff directory on site2.com. I modified to redirect to site2.com/aff/index.php\?aff=$1 etc, but maybe my browser is stuck on the previous redirect. I'll clear the cache and try again.

Comment: The site1.org condition is missing here

Comment: Then only thing missing was the aff directory in site 2, but it's working great since I added it. I do have another related question at this point. On the htaccess for this site2, I need to forward /variousdirectories to /aff/index.php?aff=variousdirectories but keep hitting endless redirect loops. Once I get THAT down, I'll work on excluding certain directories which do NOT need to be forwarded, and make pretty the URL in the aff directory (but not until the script gets that parameter), but I might actually be able to help myself on the last 2 points, just not this first one apparently.