# How to setup a permalink structure like wordpress with just postname after the domain name?

Tags: php, permalinks

My title should be enough to make you understand that what I am actually trying to do. I just want to make a simple permalink structure like this:

```
example.com/post-name
```

I have written all the code to get user request, my code is

```
$permalink = trim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/");.
```

After that I have managed to get the user request when `index.php` is added in the URL like this:

```
example.com/index.php/post-name.
```

But this is not what I am trying to achieve, I just want to simple URL structure like this:

```
example.com/post-name.
```

I want a way so that I can get user request without any need of `index.php` in the URL.

Thanks, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

See: [Redirect everything to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669258/redirect-everything-to-index-php)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but will this work on Xamp?? And can you please tell me the exact location of htaccess for xamp where I need to add these lines:

Comment: It should, XAMPP usually has mod_rewrite enabled. Just put it in the same directory as the `index.php`. Make sure that Windows does not add a `.txt` suffix, the filename must be exactly `.htaccess`.

Comment: Windows is actually changing the file name. Don't know what to do :(. It keeps deleting the . from htaccess

Comment: Use a IDE like PhpStorm, Eclipse or NetBeans. Or maybe you can do it using `cmd`.